# Will it improve SEO to clean up my WordPress tags?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, tags

I have had a website for 6 years and I create post for it every week.
From the start (6 years ago to 8 month ago), I attached familiar tags to every post.  Now:

- Some of my posts (100 posts) have many tags (about 20 tags per post)
- Some of my posts (210 posts) have tags that not good for SEO (like 'mobile', 'mobile programming', 'how to mobile programming', 'what is mobile programming' in one post)

I want to change my vision and grow my website.  I want to post everyday and create a store side of site. To do so,  I want to improve my site's SEO.

1. Which is better to do?

   - Leave the previous posts and focus on the new ones.
   - In addition to focusing on new posts, edit previous posts.
2. Which is better?

   - remove bad tags from all posts
   - leave it alone and just focus on future posts
3. If better to remove bad tags from posts, Which is better?

   - redirect tag URLs to a general tag (301)
   - redirect tag URLs to post tag (301)
   - redirect tag URLs to the homepage (410)